# Java exception only print message

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an exception class, which I will be throwing on many places in my code, but I don't want it to crash the program everytime it is called. I want only some message to be appeared (printed in console). This is my class structure so far:

```
public class CallException extends Exception {

    CallException(String message) {
        super(message);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Hovewer, everytime I throw `CallException`, it stops the program completely (with that message). I don't want it. Can you help me or can you see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `try { //some code} catch (//your exception here){//do something with your exception}`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: You can use reference [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Comment: Use logging rather than exceptions if you only want information. Exceptions are designed for things that are not supposed to happen. They either need to be caught and handled, or to crash your program which is probably better than going on in an unknown state.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to exit the program on exceptions, there are 2 ways:

1. Use try catch blocks.
2. Instead of creating exception class, create simple class with static method which prints your message.